# Sed to replace a speccificc part of line by argument in shell script based in line number

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a script **test.sh**
He has some arguments like :

```
./test.sh Forest Cuba World Hello
```

I made a while read loop to replace each specific part of a line (extractReplaceArgLine) with argument passed in shell script (Forest Cuba World Hello).

```
while read line
do
    extractReplaceArgLine=$(echo "${line}" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
    echo "${line}" | sed -e "s/"${extractReplaceArgLine}"/What I put Here ?/"
done < test.txt
```

Consider the file test.txt :

```
Ocean is incredible
Spain is my favorite country
Moon calls me everyday
Goodbye World
```

So, the output would be :

```
Forest is incredible
Cuba is my favorite country
World calls me everyday
Hello World
```

How can I do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$1` to get the first argument, and then use `shift` to shift the arguments down. Doing this in a loop will process each argument in sequence.

There's also no need to use `cut` and `sed`, you can use the shell's built-in operations.

```
while read firstword restofline
do
    echo "$1 $restofline"
    shift
done < test.txt
```